# Notation for iterative process on set

Tags: notation

*How can I define a software program's iterative function with the below defined constraints using mathematical notation?*

- $T$ is the set of individual glyphs that are stringed together in a container (png file), called $I$.
- One iteration results in $t_i$ being identified (boxed) in $I$, the result being $I_i$; $I_i$ is the input to the next iteration.

  - That is, $t_i+1$ is now identified in $I_i$, the result of which is $I_i+1$
- The final result is $I_n$ where all $t$ have been identified.

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't fill me with great confidence.

$\sum\limits_{t = 0}^n f(t, I_{t-1}) = I_t $

Comment: It sounds like each $I_{t+1}$ is the result of applying a single function to the previous $I_{t}$. If that's the case, and the initial input is $I_0$, maybe you want to write something like "$I_{t+1}=f\left(I_t\right)$ for $0\le t\le N-1$" and then explain what $f$ is? I am posting this as a comment rather than an answer because it's not totally clear what you want to express, or why mathematical notation would be a good way to express it.

Comment: Yes, your intuition is correct, the result of one computation is the input to the next. I wonder if this captures the ideas you talk about: $ I_{k+1} := f(T_k, I_k) = T_k \cup I_k, \text{for } k = 0\leq{k}\leq{|T|} $. The result of $f$ is the union of the two sets, $T_k$ being a subset of $I_k-1$.